Usage of MPI_Errhandler_free()
Section 9.3.5 of the MPI Standard documentation states:

int MPI_Errhandler_free(MPI_Errhandler *errhandler) : Marks the error handler associated with errhandler for deallocation and sets errhandler to MPI_ERRHANDLER_NULL. The error handler will be deallocated after all the objects associated with it (communicator, window, or file) have been deallocated.

According to that sentence, is the following pattern correct usage (C++):
    MPI_Errhandler errhandler;
    MPI_Comm_create_errhandler(custom_error_handler_func, &errhandler);
    MPI_Comm_set_errhandler(comm, errhandler);
    MPI_Errhandler_free(&errhandler);
    // errhandler goes out of scope here..
}
// A lot of code follows here.. then in another function, an MPI command is called on 
// the comm (communicator handle), e.g. MPI_Send():

MPI_Send(
   &variable,
   /*count=*/1,
   /*datatype=*/MPI_DOUBLE,
   /*dest_rank=*/0,
   /*tag=*/SomeTag,
   comm
);

That is: will the custom error handler be active for the last MPI_Send() above even if MPI_Errhandler_free() was called previously? Just trying to confirm my interpretation of the documentation: That it is safe to free the error handler, as long as the communicator is still alive and holding on to a reference.

I added a paragraph to my answer after you accepted it, so just a ping

All opaque MPI handles are defined this way:
You can free them as soon as you don't want to directly reference them in an MPI function. The implementation needs to take care of the necessary reference counting.
For the error handler, there is not even ref counting necessary, since the implementation can just store the callback function pointer in the communicator descriptor and doesn't even need the error handler object afterwards. The implementation will probably also need to store whether the callback is to C or Fortran because of different calling conventions.
You can later even call MPI_Comm_get_errhandler to get an error handler handle with the same settings to use it with a different communicator. You should release such handle as well with the free call.

"For the error handler, there is not even ref counting necessary" : Looking at the source  for MPI_Comm_set_errhandler()  I see that it uses reference counting though..

@HåkonHægland this is one possible implementation. :) If the implementation keeps the information in an extra object, sure it needs ref counting. My argument was that there is quite limited information to be stored in an error handler object, which could be directly copied to the communicator object to avoid the need for ref counting. At the end, this free function is probably one of the most rarely called free functions, so I guess it's not worth treating it specially.
